# Testing Conversion Rates

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, proportion

I've tried researching this problem but I'm not sure the appropriate test or how to proceed. For multiple websites I wanted to determine if changing verbiage in the checkout process would lead to lower cart abandonment.

I've taken the sites and randomly assignment them to two groups. Group A had the new verbiage for a month while Group B did not. After the month I swapped things (Group A had the old verbiage for a month while Group B had the new verbiage). The flopping was to try to remove a temporal component while being able to create a paired test (a before change and after change).

Researching things, I'm not sure I can use a paired test as even though it's a change to the site, its different people checking out. I have this data and am trying to figure out how to test this to make valid conclusions.